# Can not connect to postgresql which is inside of a docker container

Tags: postgresql, go, docker, docker-compose

I'm writing a go app which is dockerized in 2 containers: db and app.

while starting containers 'docker-compose up' I see the message: *dial tcp: lookup dbpgsql on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host*

```
DB_ENV_DB=cldb
DB_ENV_USER=cldb
DB_ENV_PASS=cldb
DB_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR=dbpgsql
DB_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT=5432
```

here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  server:
    hostname: app
    image: golang:1.7.3-alpine
    build: ./server/
    privileged: true
    container_name: server
    command: go run server.go
    volumes:
      - ../src/:/go/src/
      - ../server.go:/go/server.go
    links:
      - db:db
    ports:
     - '8080:8080'
   env_file: environment

 db:
   hostname: dbpgsql
   image: postgres:latest
   container_name: db
   environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: cldb
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: cldb
      POSTGRES_DB: cldb
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
   volumes:
     - ./data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

The app fails here when DB.Ping() is executed:

```
func InitDB(dataSourceName string) {
    var err error
    DB, err = sql.Open("postgres", dataSourceName)
    if err != nil {
       log.Panic(err)
    }

    if err = DB.Ping(); err != nil {
       log.Panic(err)
    }

    DB.SetMaxIdleConns(100)
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to map port 53 in your docker images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can connect to database with the service name (or alias name given in links options), in your case it's `db`. Hostname option sets the hostname by which the container knows itself. But  it will not appear in docker ps nor in the /etc/hosts file of any other container. (https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using `container_name` in my post-gres service and thats what was required to be set as hostname while connecting to db in application